# C++ code loop issue

Tags: c++

I have the following code that prompts the user to enter a code that contains only numbers. If the user enters two times an invalid code, the program goes further without a valid code.

```
int main()
{
    char code[10];
    cout << "Enter the code: ";
    cin >> code;

    int codeLength = strlen(code);
    int i = 0;
    while (code[i] >= '0' && code[i] <= '9')
        i++;

    if (i != codeLength)
    {
        cout << "The code is not valid: " << codDat << endl;
        cout << "Enter the code again: ";
        cin >> code;
    }

    cout << code <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I prompt the user to enter a new code until the entered code contains only numbers? I’ve already tried this:

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the code again: ";
   cin >> code;
} while (code[i] >= '0' && code[i] <= '9');
```

This code only checks the first character, but I can’t figure out how to make the right loop.

Comment: Combine the two bits of code with `while (i != codelength);` at the end.

Comment: How many digits is the user supposed to enter? Can't you attempt to read it as an integer instead of a string?

Comment: move the check to a function, this makes it much easier for you to follow the code

Comment: *If the user enters two times an invalid code, the program goes further without a valid code.* -- And if the user enters more than 9 characters, your program is hosed.

Comment: You will need to wrap your actual code you are doing to read a code and validate it inside another loop which ends when the code the user enters is valid

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This question is well-written containing example code and the problem adequately detailed.

Comment: Read into a std::string rather than a char array - then you won't get problems if the user enters `012345678901234567890.`

Comment: @Bathsheba: I wasn't the down-voter, but I was seriously considering it on the basis that this is not a "how to program" site, but a question and answer site.  The OP needs a good book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be inclined to read a `std::string`:

```
std::string foo;
cin >> foo;
```

Then use

`bool is_only_digits = std::all_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), ::isdigit);`

to check if the input contains only numbers. (You can also use `foo.size()` to check the string length).

This will be *much* easier to fashion into a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try by modifying your code as below.

```
while(true)
{
    i=0;

    while(i<codeLength && code[i] >= '0' && code[i] <= '9')
        i++;

    if(i != codeLength)
    {
        cout << "The code is not valid: " << codDat << endl;
        cout << "Enter the code again: ";
        cin >> code;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```